# Reactive Spring cloud stream who does the subscribing

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, reactive-streams

I use kafka and spring cloud stream in functional programing model.
I want to use the reactive api

So I have a Function bean that takes Flux and return flux
The returned flux is created in separate class

Do I need to subscribe to activate the new/return flux?

Answer (score 0):

That will not work if I understand you correctly. The expectation for "streaming cases" is that your function adds operations to the incoming flux and returns it. The framework will subscribe to what your function has returned and the stream begins. Because of that if you create a new instance of Flux it would not work.
What I mean it is by design.
Once we have truly reactive binders (which we don't at the moment)then things will change.

Comment: I have got inspired by methos named singleInputMultipleOutputs on  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/MultipleInputOutputFunctionTests.java#L342  .   I want to create 2 Flux with method asFlux() called on 2 new sinks created by me

Comment: So yes, the above test and this one https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-context/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/context/catalog/BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistryMultiInOutTests.java kind of gives you idea of what is supported. But in the nutshell the output should be connected derivative of input, otherwise it will not work. That said, if you subscribe in your implementation to the input and produce some output that framework would subscribe, that should work i assume, but I have not tried  it yet. Feel free to raise an issue.

Comment: I see...thank you very much